# Jenkins "Unable to create the home directory"

Tags: jenkins

The complete error message is:

> Unable to create the home directory ‘/var/lib/tomcat8/.jenkins’. This is most likely a permission problem.
>
> To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system property. See Container-specific documentation for more details of how to do this.

After trying to set the permissions proper and failing, I finally did the following:

```
sudo chmod ugo+rwx /var/lib/tomcat8
```

But I get the same error message. I also tried this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat8/.jenkins
sudo chmod ugo+rwx /var/lib/tomcat8/.jenkins
```

yet still the same. I'm thinking at this point that it's not a permission problem. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Jenkins solved the problem.